# Playframework - Request[A] vs RequestHeader

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm unable to understand diffrence between `play.api.mvc.Request[A]` and `play.api.mvc.RequestHeader` and `play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]`.

---

In compiled class I've got

```
trait Request[+A] extends scala.AnyRef with play.api.mvc.RequestHeader {
  def $init$() : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  def body : A
  def map[B](f : scala.Function1[A, B]) : play.api.mvc.Request[B] = { /* compiled code */ }
}
object Request extends scala.AnyRef {
  def apply[A](rh : play.api.mvc.RequestHeader, a : A) : scala.AnyRef with play.api.mvc.Request[A] {
  val remoteAddress : scala.Predef.String
  def username : scala.None.type
  val body : A
} = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

#### Request[AnyContent] ---> RequestWithUser[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] ?

```
def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String)], msg: Option[String]): Html = {
    val req = RequestWithUser(None, request)
    views.html.secure.login(form, msg)(request = req)
  }
```

This code works in `TemplatePlugin` but it's not working in view:

```
@(loginForm: play.api.data.Form[(String,String)], errorMsg: Option[String] = None)(implicit request: securesocial.core.RequestWithUser[_ <: play.api.mvc.AnyContent])
```

It's not working because:

```
type mismatch; found : securesocial.core.RequestWithUser[A] required: securesocial.core.RequestWithUser[_ <: play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
```

So I tried to put `AnyContent` as generic type:

```
def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String)], msg: Option[String]): Html = {
    val req = RequestWithUser[play.api.mvc.AnyContent](None, request)
    views.html.secure.login(form, msg)(request = req)
  }
```

But next compilation error shown:

```
type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.Request[A] required: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
```

And play.api.mvc.AnyContent looks like:

```
package play.api.mvc
sealed trait AnyContent extends scala.AnyRef {
  def $init$() : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  def asFormUrlEncoded : scala.Option[scala.Predef.Map[scala.Predef.String, scala.Seq[scala.Predef.String]]] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def asText : scala.Option[scala.Predef.String] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def asXml : scala.Option[scala.xml.NodeSeq] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def asJson : scala.Option[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def asMultipartFormData : scala.Option[play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData[play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile]] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def asRaw : scala.Option[play.api.mvc.RawBuffer] = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

---

## Edited - solution so far

---

I found code that compiles and even works well. Nevertheless this is not elegant way because I used `asInstanceOf` and cast class.

```
def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String)], msg: Option[String]): Html = {
    implicit val r = RequestWithUser[play.api.mvc.AnyContent](None, request.asInstanceOf[Request[AnyContent]])
    views.html.secure.login(form, msg)(request = r)
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RequestHeader` represents the header of the HTTP request.  `Request[A]` is a `RequestHeader` plus a parsed request body of `A`.  The default body parser in Play detects a few well known body formats (`application/json`, `application/xml`, `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`), and parses them automatically into a body of type `AnyContent`, which then lets you access the specific types by calling methods such as `asJson`.  If you write an action like:

```
def myAction = Action { req =>
  ...
}
```

Then the type of `req` will be `Request[AnyContent]`.  On the other hand, if you explicitly specify a body parser, then the type of the request will be the type that that body parser returns, for example:

```
def myAction = Action(parse.json) { req =>
  ...
}
```

In that case, `req` will be `Request[JsValue]`.  So, the secure social template wants a `Request[AnyContent]`, so firstly, this means you can only use it from actions that use the default body parser.  Next, it means that you have to change the signature of your `getLoginPage` to only accept `Request[AnyContent]`, eg:

```
def getLoginPage(implicit request: Request[AnyContent], form: Form[(String, String)], msg: Option[String]): Html = {
  val req = RequestWithUser(None, request)
  views.html.secure.login(form, msg)(request = req)
}
```

That should work as is, as long as every action that invokes `getLoginPage` has a request that has been produced by the default body parser.

Comment: One thing - method signature cannot change :/

Comment: Why can't you change the signature?  Also, did you write the template?  If you did, then why don't you change the signature of the template to accept Request[_]?  If the template must receive something of type AnyContent, then that means that it's going to try to use the body somehow, which means casting will probably cause a runtime error.

Comment: I wrote template, but template must be like this because main.scala.html has the same parameters. I also cannot change method signature because it's part of SecureSocial and there is a plugin TemplatePlugin which has to be implemented to work correctly.

Comment: If the main template takes `RequestHeader`, then there's nothing stopping you from passing the `Request[AnyContent]` into it, since `Request` extends `RequestHeader`.